# Python how do I catch the list case in a custom JSON encoder?

Tags: python, json

Im trying to write a custom Json encoder for an existing Datastructure. It contains a List of Containers with names, values and descriptions. The List needs to be transformed to a Dictionary before its turned into JSON. Because the Container may also contain a list of containers I wanted to use the JSON encoders recursive behaviour to make it simpler. However I'm unable to make my encoder go into the list case.

```
import json
from functools import reduce


class ContainerEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            if reduce(lambda a, b: a and isinstance(b, Container), obj, True):
                return {x.get_name(): {"prop": x.get_prop(), "desc": x.get_desc()} for x in ContainerStore}
            else:
                return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
        if isinstance(obj, Container):
            return {obj.get_name(): {"prop": obj.get_prop(), "desc": obj.get_desc()}}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    
class Container:
    def __init__(self, name: str, prop: any = None, desc: str = ""):
        self._name = name
        self._prop = prop
        self._desc = desc

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def get_prop(self):
        return self._prop

    def get_desc(self):
        return self._desc


C1 = Container("Container1", 12, "Container Holding a Number")
C2 = Container("Container2", True, "Container Holding a Boolean Value")
C3 = Container("CoolContainer", [1, 2, 3, 4], "Container Holding a List")

ContainerStore = [C1, C2, C3]
ContainerDict = {x.get_name(): {"prop": x.get_prop(), "desc": x.get_desc()} for x in ContainerStore}
dump1 = json.dumps(ContainerStore, cls=ContainerEncoder)
print(dump1)
dump2 = json.dumps(ContainerDict)
print(dump2)
```

The problem seems to be that isinstance(obj, list) never returns true and so it always uses the Standard Encoder to encode the List and then encodes all the containers individually.

`print(isinstance(ContainerStore, list))`
is True so it should work but I'm pretty new to Python so any help is appreciated

Comment: I believe the `default()` method is only called for object types that the encoder doesn't know how to handle.  So your custom method is called for the _contents_ of the list, but not for the list object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `obj` is always going to be of type `Container` because that is what the JSON module passes to your encoder. Instead of `isinstance(obj, list)` try using `isinstance(obj.get_prop(), list)` to test the instance of the property.